# jquery effect for to simulate turning pages in a book

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Looking for an effect similar to: http://issuu.com/nanomag/docs/nano_light

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/jquery/animate4.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin -

http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/demo.html

You can also check the below link , it contains detailed step by step explanation for implementing this -

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2007/07/20/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks but I'm really looking for something much more like the examle I gave earlier.